# PyQt technique differences in 2 source code examples

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

These 2 programs work the same, but there is a small difference in the lines marked with #HERE.
Can someone explain the differences?  I do not fully understand what these lines do.

Program 1:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class myform(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myform, self).__init__(parent)

        form = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        form.setHorizontalSpacing(0)

        myedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        form.addWidget(myedit)

        self.setLayout(form)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 0)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')

        myedit.textChanged.connect(self.editchange)   # new style signal slot connections

        self.show()                      # HERE

    def editchange(self,data):
        print "editchange:", data

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ex = myform()

    #ex.exec_()                          # HERE
    #sys.exit(app.closeAllWindows())     # HERE

    sys.exit(app.exec_())                # HERE
```

Program #2:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class myform(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myform, self).__init__(parent)

        form = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        form.setHorizontalSpacing(0)

        myedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        form.addWidget(myedit)

        self.setLayout(form)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 0)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')

        myedit.textChanged.connect(self.editchange)   # new style signal slot connections

        #self.show()                      # HERE

    def editchange(self,data):
        print "editchange:", data

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ex = myform()

    ex.exec_()                          # HERE
    sys.exit(app.closeAllWindows())     # HERE

    #sys.exit(app.exec_())                # HERE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program #1 calls `exec_` from QApplication (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#exec).

Program #2 calls `exec_` from QDialog (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html#exec): the resulting dialog is a modal one.

The final behavior is the same because you use a QDialog.

In this case:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
ex = myform()
ex.show()
app.exec_()
```

is the same as:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
ex = myform()
ex.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It seems to me that program #1 would therefore be the more typical approach then?

Comment: Yes the first case will work for any widget other than QDialog.